# dbml Serialzable= Unidirection, but 'System.Data.Linq.EntityRef' still not mark as Serialzable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, serialization

I need a linq-to-sql use dbml, then I follow this article : http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/147218.aspx

Set the child to internal, set serialzable to unidirection and add updatecheck=never

Make everything column

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_DvdId",
  AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true,
  IsDbGenerated=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=1)]
```

But I still get

> Type 'System.Data.Linq.EntityRef`1[[CategoryList, App_Code.55_rpva1, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

In my `web.config`, I use Binary

```
<add name="Cart" type="ShoppingCart" serializeAs="Binary" allowAnonymous="true"/>
```

If I don't use linq, it surely works

Please help

Answer (score 2):

It is *serializable*, but simply not via `BinaryFormatter`*- i.e. it isn't `[Serializable]` or `ISerializable`.

LINQ data-contexts are designed to be serialized with `DataContractSerializer`, however - for binary, either `NetDataContractSerializer` or protobuf-net should also work fine.

If this is *profile* serialization.... I honestly don't know if you can write your own plugin serialization layer - I've never had need to look; but in this case I would write a simple, non-LINQ object (a DTO) for the object properties that I **actually need** in my profile, and just populate that object from LINQ, and serialize *that*.

---

*=for what it is worth, I don't consider this a bad thing; `BinaryFormatter` has so many ways of causing pain that actively *not* supporting it is actually a *positive* thing, by virtue of finally weaning people of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using restrictor attributes for serialization works for me:

```
[Column]
[DataMember]
public int? MonitoredDirectorySubCategoryID { set; get; }

[NonSerialized]
[XmlIgnore]
[IgnoreDataMember]
private EntityRef<BasicReference> _MonitoredDirectorySubCategory = new EntityRef<BasicReference>();

[XmlIgnore]
[IgnoreDataMember]
[Association(Name = "FK_FilRef_BasRef_MonitoredDirectorySubCategoryID", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_MonitoredDirectorySubCategory", ThisKey = "MonitoredDirectorySubCategoryID")]
public BasicReference MonitoredDirectorySubCategory 
{ set { _MonitoredDirectorySubCategory.Entity = value; } get { return _MonitoredDirectorySubCategory.Entity; } }
```